# How to AppPermissionRequest for more than one generic list?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, provider-hosted-app

I am working on a SharePoint 2013 Online - Provider Hosted App, which needs to have write access on two generic lists.

Instead of requesting access on web is it possible to request app access for two individual generic lists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, the permission request framework does not provide for this.

Instead, I would create ListTemplates for your lists, which will give them unique template IDs. Then, you can specify the ID in the permission request:

```
<AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/sitecollection/web/list"
                      Right="Write">
  <Property Name="BaseTemplateId" Value="{YOUR_ID_HERE}"/>
</AppPermissionRequest>
```

You would then repeat that request, changing the ID as appropriate.